# Highcharts replacing column/tooltip label

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Is there any solution to replace Y column label **"0"** to **"∞"** (infinity) simbol?
Futhermore, I need **"∞"** insted of **"0"** in Highcharts tooltip.

Should I simply use `formatter: function()`?

[Test example](http://jsfiddle.net/falcon4fun/LCz7Y/) is here.

Thank you for assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value || '∞';
        }
    }
},
```

Is the second question mean: "∞" replace Y value "0" in Highcharts tooltip?

Comment: As I understand, yes. I've done myself for tooltip.

`formatter: function() { return "This value is <b>"+ (Math.round(this.y) || '∞')+"</b>";},`


Thank you ;)